# Right justified numbers in Perl

Tags: perl, right-justified

How can I print numbers right justified in Perl, like this:

```
a=   1
b=  22
c= 333
d=4444
```

Answer (score 10):

Try like  this.

```
printf ("%4d\n",1);
printf ("%4d\n",11);
printf ("%4d\n",111);
printf ("%4d\n",1111);
```

Answer (score 5):

The official resource for this is [`perldoc -f sprintf`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html) , which has a nice summary of examples:

> For example:
>
> ```
>   printf '<% d>',  12;   # prints "< 12>"
>   printf '<%+d>',  12;   # prints "<+12>"
>   printf '<%6s>',  12;   # prints "<    12>"
>   printf '<%-6s>', 12;   # prints "<12    >"
>   printf '<%06s>', 12;   # prints "<000012>"
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Use `printf` with a precision and a space as "filler":

```
printf "a=% 4d\n", 1;
printf "b=% 4d\n", 22;
```